# How can I programmatically hide the title bar similar to how QuickTime player works?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mac-catalyst

When I'm watching a video file the title bar and the controls disappear after a while leaving only the movie.

[image]

[image]

How can I achieve the same behavior?

I know how to make the title bar disappear using this code:

```
- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene willConnectToSession:(UISceneSession *)session options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    
#if TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST
    // Code specific to Mac.
    
    [(UIWindowScene *)scene titlebar].titleVisibility = UITitlebarTitleVisibilityHidden;
    
    [(UIWindowScene *)scene titlebar].toolbar = nil;
    
#else
    // Code to exclude from Mac.
#endif

}
```

But the three dots (minimize, maximize and close) remain:

[image]

In the example above I'm using a WKWebView.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
if #available(macOS 10.10, *) {
    window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
}

if #available(macOS 10.2, *) {
    window.movableByWindowBackground  = true
}
```

Comment: I'm running the iOS app in macOS via MacCatalyst so what I'm using is a UIWindow not an NSWindow. The UIWindow doesn't have the "titlebarAppearsTransparent" or "movableByWindowBackground" properties.